# Creating a calender using php, javascript and mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created a calender using php, javascript and mySQL.

The calender itself worked but once I attempted to add and view events on a particular day it refuses to load and I'm not too sure why. This example is taken from Sam's teach yourself PHP, MySQL and Apache all in one.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php
//$display = "";
$host = "xx";
$user = "xx";
$pass = "xx";
$db = "xx";

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
// Check connection

define("ADAY", (60*60*24));
if ((!isset($_POST['month'])) || (!isset($_POST['year']))) {
$nowArray = getdate();
$month = $nowArray['mon'];
$year = $nowArray['year'];
} else {
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
}
$start = mktime (12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$firstDayArray = getdate($start);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo "Calender: ".$firstDayArray['month']."
".$firstDayArray['year'] ?></title>
 </head>
 <style type="text/css">
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ccc;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 6px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width 100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function eventWindow(url) {
event_popupWin = window.open(url, 'event', 'resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes,          toolbar=no, width=400, height=400');
    event_popupWin.opener = self;
}
</script>
<body>
<h1>Select a Month/Year Combination</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name ="month">
<?php
$months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",       "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
for ($x=1; $x <= count($months); $x++) {
echo"<option value=\." $x ".\"";
if ($x == $month) {
    echo " selected";
}
echo ">".$months[$x-1]."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="year">
<?php
for ($x=1990; $x<=2020; $x++) {
echo "<option";
if ($x == $year) {
    echo " selected";
}
echo ">." $x ."</option>";
  }
  ?>
 </select>
 <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Go!</button>
 </form>
<br/>
<?php
$days = Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
echo "<table><tr>\n";
foreach ($days as $day) {
echo "<th>$day</th>\n";
}
for ($count=0; $count < (6*7); $count++) { //initialise a variable called count
$dayArray = getdate($start);
if (($count% 7) == 0) {
    if ($dayArray['mon'] != $month) {
        break;
} else {
    echo "</tr><tr>\n";
}
}
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] || $dayArray['mon'] !=$month) {
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
} else {
   echo "<td>".$dayArray['mday']."</td>\n"; 
   $start += ADAY;
}
}
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] || $dayArray['mon'] !=$month) {
echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
} else {
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $chkEvent_sql = "SELECT event_title FROM calender_events WHERE
        month(event_start) = '".$month."' AND
        dayofmonth(event_start) = '".$dayArray['mday']."' AND 
        year(event_start) = '".$year."' 
        ORDER BY event_start";

    $chkEvent_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $chkEvent_sql);
                        or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


            if (mysqli_num_rows($chkEvent_res) > 0) {
                while ($ev = mysqli_fetch_array($chkEvent_res)) {
                    $event_title .=    stripslashes($ev['event_title']);
            }
 } else {
    event_title = "";
}

echo "<td><a href=\"javascript:eventWindow('event.php?m=   ".$month."&amp;d=".$dayArray['mday']."&amp;y=".$year."');/>".$dayArray['mday']."</a><br/>  <br/>".$event_title."</td>\n";

        unset($event_title);

        $start += ADAY; 

}
echo "</tr><table>";
?>
<body>
</html>
```

However, I believe the problem is with this section code:

```
$chkEvent_res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $chkEvent_sql);
                        or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


            if (mysqli_num_rows($chkEvent_res) > 0) {
                while ($ev = mysqli_fetch_array($chkEvent_res)) {
                    $event_title .=       stripslashes($ev['event_title']);
            }
} else {
    event_title = "";
}

echo "<td><a href=\"javascript:eventWindow('event.php?m= ".$month."&amp;d=".$dayArray['mday']."&amp;y=".$year."');/>".$dayArray['mday']."</a><br/> <br/>".$event_title."</td>\n";
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Or a more detailed description of the error,  you're probably getting an error on the javascript console, that should help.

Comment: I'm not getting any error in my JavaScript element which is confusing me. I've checked the SQL code in a simulator by inserting dummy data and it seems to produce a successful result. When I go to inspect the element no code appears

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **Avoid** using string interpolation to accomplish this. You have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code here that need to be fixed.